# как получить массив чисел?

Tags: javascript

Как получить массив чисел [1,2,4] из строки 'fgfgfg gfgfg 1 2 4 fhh , fff , hghg"?

Comment: Регулярным выражением `/[\d]+/g`

Comment: А [Ирина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/268345/%D0%98%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) - это тоже вы?